# What does the expression "we are looking to you" mean?

Tags: idioms, expressions, meaning-in-context

What does the expression "we are looking to you" mean in the following sentence?

> Now that you have taken the test and have an understanding, **we are looking to you** to teach this to your subordinates.

Answer (score 15):

It means "we are expecting you" or "we have selected you".

Vague wording of this sort is sometimes used in an attempt to be less blunt (i.e to appear more polite) - as if they are merely hoping that you will be happy to volunteer your services.

Imagine a group of people standing in a circle, the leader asks "who can we get to teach the subordinates?" then she stares directly at you and waits in silence. The leader is looking to[wards] you.

Comment: Ahahahaah, I loved the example =D.
Thank you so much for the fast and clear answer!

Answer (score 11):

The Phrasal Verb "[look to + someone](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/look%5B1%5D)" means:

- to need someone to do something for you

or

- to depend or rely on someone

Examples from Merriam-Webster include

> • They look to me to fix the problem.
>   • She looked to her friends for help.
>   • Many parents look to their children to help them navigate the Internet.